# Issue in Building a Docker Image with Maven

Tags: spring-boot, docker, maven, apple-m1

I m trying to build docker image for springboot project using below command ,

```
./mvnw spring-boot:build-image -Dspring-boot.build-image.imageName=myorg/myapp
```

**error ,**

```
[INFO]  > Using build cache volume 'pack-cache-152f93393a7f.build'
[INFO] 
[INFO]  > Running creator
[INFO]     [creator]     Previous image with name "myorg/myapp:latest" not found
[INFO]     [creator]     ===> DETECTING
[INFO]     [creator]     qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
```

**My machine details are:**

```
macOsBigSur
Version - 11.2.2
Chip - Apple M1
RAM - 16 GB
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Are you really looking for `springio/gs-spring-boot-docker` ?

Comment: it did't worked for any other image name as well , same issue . @HermannSteidel

Comment: Apple M1 is known for having issues with docker. It may actually be the reason of your problem. Not sure where this issue is at right now. See if any of the recommendations here helps: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/apple-silicon/

Comment: which version of docker or docker desktop are you using it?